# How to map an element's children to their data attribute values?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dictionary

Given a parent element, how can I get a collection with all the `data-chartid` attribute values?

```html
<div id="chart-container">
  <div data-chartid="1">...</div >
  <div data-chartid="2">...</div >
  <div data-chartid="3">...</div >
</div>
```

I'm trying to duplicate the syntax used on [this page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), but it seems to fail on several levels.

`$('#chart-container').children().map(c => $(c).data('chartid'))`

*Note: All top-level children are `<div>`s so maybe the selector could be modified so `children()` isn't necessary.*

Comment: Adding some example Html would improve your post.

Comment: The first argument to the callback is the index, not the element.

Comment: @Unmitigated: I don't think that's what I want. I'm going after what's on [this page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

Comment: @JonathanWood I've updated my answer. It should look like your syntax now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first parameter passed to the `map` callback is the index. The second is the item:

```js
const res = $('#chart-container').children().map((index, elem) => $(elem).data('chartid')).toArray()
console.log(res)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="chart-container">
  <span data-chartid="one"></span>
  <span data-chartid="two"></span>
  <span data-chartid="three"></span>
</div>
```

If you want to duplicate the syntax:

```js
const res = $('#chart-container').children().toArray().map(e => $(e).data('chartid'))
console.log(res)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="chart-container">
  <span data-chartid="one"></span>
  <span data-chartid="two"></span>
  <span data-chartid="three"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. Of the two, your revised first example seems shorter. Can you tell me what `map()` is returning before calling `toArray()`?

Comment: @JonathanWood The first example uses jQuery's `map`, which passes the index as the first param and the element as the second. The second example uses the default array map, which passes the array item (the element) to the callback.

Comment: Yes, I understand the code. My question was about what `map()` is returning before calling `toArray()`? What type of object?

Comment: @JonathanWood It returns an array like object with some other jQuery fields, so it's not really a "pure" array

Comment: @JonathanWood you wouldn't be able to call the normal array methods on it, like `forEach`